# Stop user selecting entire row/column in excel

Tags: excel

How can I stop a user selecting an entire row or column in excel? The problem is that user selects the row to take the data they want, but they also get a bunch of hidden cells etc. that I don't want them to take.

Answer (score 2):

Lock the hidden cells, unlock everything else and protect the worksheet with the sole restriction of Select locked cells (allow everything else).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've tried this and the only problem is that now when the user uses the arrow keys to navigate it seems to only move between cells that have been edited, and jumps from the top leftmost to the bottom rightmost if I press left (where as I'd like it to not move if it's at A1 and I press left).

Comment: It sounds as if the worksheet has already been protected under different restrictions than the one listed above.